# Destroy without callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to skip callbacks for particular destroy method.

```
@object.destroy //but no callbacks, like after_commit
```

I'm not looking for `delete`. Because `delete` will delete the object only. It won't take care of the associated child objects. As `destroy` will destroy the dependent children too.

Comment: I agree, `delete` is "destroy without the callbacks".

Comment: Because `delete` will delete the object only. It won't take care of the associated child objects. As `destroy` will destroy the dependent children too.

Comment: you can used `skip_callback` then destroy current object

Comment: @leo use foreign_keys with `on_delete: :cascade` set, then the database will delete the child objects.

Comment: @j-dexx, sounds good, thanks. but actually i want to disable callback on this specific point only. I want the callbacks to work properly, if the object is destroyed from any other point.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that:

- If you want to do this just once, you should delete it with Relations through database or console manually
- If you want this behaviour as permanent, you need to change your foreign_keys to have `on_delete` as somebody suggested in the comments already.

For example:

`def change
  add_foreign_key :childrentable, :object, on_delete: :cascade
end`

That would change your ChildrenTable table foreign_key object_id to have `ON DELETE CASCADE`